# selectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync not returning success even when cccdValue = indicate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am modifying a BLE code on UWP in Visual Studio. I am able to read service and characterstic but when I subscribe for value changes I get an error. 
In the below code i get the status as 'Unreachable' even when `cccdValue = indicate`

```
status = await 
selectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(cccdValue);

if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
    AddValueChangedHandler();
    rootPage.NotifyUser("Successfully subscribed for value changes", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your cccdValue actually decared as GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Indicate?

Comment: This below condition check if it is a indicate or notify-                          
 if (selectedCharacteristic.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Indicate))
                {
                    cccdValue = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Indicate;
                }    // this initializes my cccd value as indicate

Comment: There seems to be no problem with your code. Have you checked the checkbox bluetooth in Package.appXmanifest capabilities?

Comment: Christ, at least try to format your code.